# dkms Installed kernel module but not working after reboot

Tags: drivers, kernel, keyboard, usbhid

I bought a keyboard that is shown on `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 0c45:7603 Microdia
```

but the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Windows</kbd>/<kbd>Super</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> buttons are all mapped to <kbd>Shift</kbd> button. So I followed the hardware code and find this solution [here](https://bitbucket.org/Swoogan/aziokbd), which works fine:

```
dkms status aziokbd
aziokbd, 1.0.0, 3.13.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed
```

However, after reboot, the keyboard goes back to original state( ctrl/alt/win mapped to shift) while `dkms status` is same as above, so I have to `sudo dkms uninstall -m aziokbd -v 1.0.0` and install again.

How could I "save" the installed state? thank you.

I've ubuntu 14.04. Output of `uname -a`

`Linux PC 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

- **debug info after *installed, rebooted and not working*:**

  ```
  #####################
  dkms status
  ###############################

  8192cu, 1.9, 3.11.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
  8192cu, 1.9, 3.13.0-44-generic, x86_64: installed
  8192cu, 1.9, 3.13.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed
  8192cu, 1.9, 3.13.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed
  8192cu, 1.9, 3.13.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed
  8192cu, 1.9, 3.2.0-65-generic, x86_64: installed
  8192cu, 1.9, 3.2.0-67-generic, x86_64: installed
  8192cu, 1.9, 3.2.0-68-generic, x86_64: installed
  8192cu, 1.9, 3.2.0-69-generic, x86_64: installed
  8192cu, 1.9, 3.2.0-70-generic, x86_64: installed
  8192cu, 1.9, 3.2.0-72-generic, x86_64: installed
  8192cu, 1.9, 3.2.0-74-generic, x86_64: installed
  aziokbd, 1.0.0, 3.13.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed
  virtualbox, 4.3.10, 3.13.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed
  virtualbox, 4.3.10, 3.13.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed
  virtualbox-guest, 4.3.10, 3.13.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed
  virtualbox-guest, 4.3.10, 3.13.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed

  #########################################3
  lsmod | grep -e usbhid -e aziokbd 
  #######################################3

  aziokbd                12900  0 
  usbhid                 52659  0 
  hid                   106148  2 hid_generic,usbhid


  ########################################
  lsusb -t
  #####################################
  /:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
      |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
          |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
          |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
          |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
          |__ Port 3: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
          |__ Port 3: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
  /:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
      |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
          |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtl8192cu, 480M
  ```
- **debug info after reinstalled and working:**

  ```
  ###########################
  dkms status
  ###########################

  8192cu, 1.9, 3.11.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
  8192cu, 1.9, 3.13.0-44-generic, x86_64: installed
  8192cu, 1.9, 3.13.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed
  8192cu, 1.9, 3.13.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed
  8192cu, 1.9, 3.13.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed
  8192cu, 1.9, 3.2.0-65-generic, x86_64: installed
  8192cu, 1.9, 3.2.0-67-generic, x86_64: installed
  8192cu, 1.9, 3.2.0-68-generic, x86_64: installed
  8192cu, 1.9, 3.2.0-69-generic, x86_64: installed
  8192cu, 1.9, 3.2.0-70-generic, x86_64: installed
  8192cu, 1.9, 3.2.0-72-generic, x86_64: installed
  8192cu, 1.9, 3.2.0-74-generic, x86_64: installed
  aziokbd, 1.0.0, 3.13.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed
  virtualbox, 4.3.10, 3.13.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed
  virtualbox, 4.3.10, 3.13.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed
  virtualbox-guest, 4.3.10, 3.13.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed
  virtualbox-guest, 4.3.10, 3.13.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed

  ######################
  lsmod | grep -e usbhid -e aziokbd
  #########################


  usbhid                 52659  0 
  aziokbd                12900  0 
  hid                   106148  2 hid_generic,usbhid

  #########################
  lsusb -t
  ############################
  /:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
      |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
          |__ Port 1: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=aziokbd, 1.5M
          |__ Port 1: Dev 7, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=aziokbd, 1.5M
          |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
          |__ Port 3: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
          |__ Port 3: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
  /:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
      |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
          |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtl8192cu, 480M
  ```

Comment: Could you reinstall it, when it's working, post output of: `dkms status` , `lsmod | grep -e usbhid -e aziokbd` and `lsusb -t` and same after reboot when it's not working. Also you may try add `usbhid.quirks=0x0c45:0x7603:0x4` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55495/prevent-usbhid-from-claiming-usb-device . btw you need to run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: the grub command worked perfectly! Also I have posted the debug info without adding the grub command. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `usbhid` still loaded as driver for the keyboard. It seems quirks didn't work as `modprobe` option.

1. Try kernel option from grub, add:

   ```
   usbhid.quirks=0x0c45:0x7603:0x4
   ```

   to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`
2. Update grub

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

**Reference:** [Prevent usbhid from claiming USB device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55495/prevent-usbhid-from-claiming-usb-device)

Comment: Wow!  I learned something today!  (Upvoted!)